# How to count characters in keyup in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

how do you count characters including space in keyup event in angular 6?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-loop-back',
  template: `
    <input #box (keyup)="0">
    <p>{{box.value}}</p>
  `
})
export class LoopbackComponent { }
```

Comment: using `box.value.length` bro.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can count character by
`box.value.length`
or 
`box.value?.length`

`?` after the property will check for undefined..

Comment: Simplest approach +1

Comment: just come up with an answer before i look up answer here xD anyway thanks for the answer same as mine :) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qvb1ky?file=src%2Fapp%2Floop-back.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

Using 2-way binding you can bind to `box` and it will automatically update with changes.  You do not need to use a (keyup) event handler here:

```
template: `
    <input [(ngModel)]="box">
    <p>{{box.length}}</p>
  `
```

In your module import the FormsModule from here:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

And that will allow you to use ngModel.  [( )] turns on 2-way binding meaning that the display and value will automatically stay in sync without any extra logic.

Answer (score 0):

use `{{box.value.length}}`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-loop-back',
  template: `
    <input #box (keyup)="0">
    <p>{{box.value}}</p>
    <p>{{box.value.length}}</p>
  `
})
export class LoopbackComponent { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the below method :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-loop-back',
  template: `
    <input #box (keyup)="onKeyUp(box)">
    <p>{{box.value}}</p>
  `
})
export class LoopbackComponent { 

  onKeyUp(boxInput : HTMLInputElement){
    let length = boxInput.value.length ; //this will have the length of the text entered in the input box
    console.log(length);
  }
}
```